# Manage exchange 2010 calendar from SP 2013

Tags: 2013, calendar, exchange

I would like to add a functionnality in SharePoint 2013.

We're using Exchange 2010. I would like to create some infopath forms/workflows and so on, to permit a manager for example to manage project by adding/removing/modifying elements in others' exchange calendar.

I mean : In a calendar list in SP2013, if a manager got delegation permissions on Exchange's side, then he would be able to check (and manage) employees' calendar.

The goal is to manage and check lots of users's calendar with SharePoint features at the same place. And calendars must be sync with exchange so emloyees will see their calendar on their phones for example (as it'd be synced with outlook).

I really don't know if I understable, let me know if I'm not.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want this in SharePoint? Do the capabilities of Outlook Web Access not suffice for this?

Comment: Yes, I would like to manage some infopath forms to permit my manager handling employees on different projects. For example, my manager create a new item from form, he creates several tasks, and assign it to certain employees depending on their planning. If they're free, he can assign someone on a particular task for example. Everything is on SharePoi nt so. Because now, he opens an item, check date/time and skills required, open outlook and checks planning, then create event in outlook calendar ... it's not really efficient. (Again, don't know if I'm understandable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the detail in the comments above this may be possible via InfoPath Forms, although you will need to write custom code (C# or VB) behind the forms - these will use the Exchange Web Services API to perform the checks for availability and create the event in the Calendar also.

MSDN is full of information of the Exchange Web Services including code samples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm not a developper, but I can understand. I'll go through this article and talk to devs. Would you qualify this as hard to do ? Or could I just use the web page viewer webpart and put custom Exchange web Services URL ? :)

Comment: Hah, the latter certainly wouldn't work :) If you design each of the page's functionality very clearly, and state what each page needs to do, and what information it needs, and what decisions it needs to ask the user for - then this shouldn't be too difficult a task for your developers.

Note that instead of InfoPath Forms, your devs may also want to use custom web parts or even custom SharePoint Application Pages to perform this. I think it depends on your design of what the forms should do, and leave it up to your devs if they know which route to go down.

Comment: Pretty good answer :) Thanks for all @James Love. I'm sad that couldn't find any open source or at least free solution, because Bamboo and amrein.com are selling that. But couldn't find anything on codeplex. Maybe with this project https://exchangewp.codeplex.com/ that retrieve unread mails, I can use it and modify to suit my needs.